# Why can we create attributes to the object of an OrderedDict but not for Dict?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, ordereddict

When reading some code I found that one can create new attributes for an object of an OrderedDict but when I tried creating one for Python's Dict, Python didn't allow me to.

Just wondering why this happened and why it is so that one would want to create attributes for OrderedDict when they can set key-value pairs using OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1):

[`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is implemented in Python, and you can assign any attributes to a traditional Python object (with some exceptions, like when `__slots__` are defined). NB: It does not mean, that you *should* do that or that it's often a good idea, but it is possible. In particular, I don't see any valid reason 
to do that with `OrderedDict`.

`dict`, on the opposite, is a builtin object, and is implemented in C. It does not have it's own `__dict__` to store attributes, that's why you can't assign them.